# what is the most efficient & effective thread library can be used in delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

is there any thread library which can be more useful instead of the origin TThread class for delphi 2007 ?
it would be more pleasure if it is open source.. :)
thnks a lot

Comment: most efficient and effective at what? what problems do you have with the class you're mentionning?

Comment: @Mat: i mean that it can be debugged easily.. thnks for your response ..

Comment: @yuda, you question is very subjective, so i be will subjective too - the best of the best, `OmniThreadLibrary` http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/ ;)

Comment: It would be subjective if there was more than one that was really great.  OTL is that one.  :-) So just put that as an answer, RRUZ.

Comment: @Warren P, you are being subjective too ;), i don't know if add the comment, as answer because it' so easy gain some rep. points, recommending this great library, so I not sure if that answer will be a real contribution to the community.

Comment: A good link is here - http://delphi.about.com/od/kbthread/tp/threading-libraries-for-Delphi.htm

Comment: @RRUZ, Warren P, Misha : i am appriciate your your answer guys.. thnks a lot..

Answer (score 3):

OmniThreadLibrary is very good (http://otl.17slon.com/), and I have my own equivalent threading framework (http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_delphi.htm) as part of a larger distributed application framework. The main difference between the two is that Primoz's threading framework is possibly aimed at a lower level of granularity (algorithms, etc), while mine is aimed at a higher level of granularity (information exchange, etc) and inter-thread messaging and inter-process messaging share a common interface and common functionality.

Answer (score 2):

There is a full discussion of the different ways of implementing threads in Delphi at the question: 
[How Do I Choose Between the Various Ways to do Threading in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419945/how-do-i-choose-between-the-various-ways-to-do-threading-in-delphi)