# Delphi How to wait for socket answer inside procedure?

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-xe2

For some specific needs i need to create procedure that waits for socket request  (or answer) in dll:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ServerSocket1: TServerSocket;

......

procedure MyWaitProc; stdcall;
begin
  Go := false;
  while not Go do
  begin
    // Wating...
    // Application.ProcessMessages;     // Works with this line
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject;
  Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
begin
  MessageBoxA(0, PAnsiChar('Received: '+Socket.ReceiveText), '', MB_OK);
  Go := true;
end;

exports
  MyWaitProc;
```

When I call `Application.ProcessMessages` everything works fine: application waits for request and then continues. But in my case calling `Application.ProcessMessages` causes to unlocking main form on host application (not dll's one). When I don't call `Application.ProcessMessages` application just hangs couse it cannot handle message...

So, how to create such a procedure that's wating for socket answer ?
Maybe there a way to wait for socket answer without using `Application.ProcessMessages` ?

EDIT

I also tried to use TIdTCPServer, for some reasons, the result is the same.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
.....

procedure MyWaitProc; stdcall;
begin
  Go := false;
  while not Go do
  begin
    // Waiting ...
    // Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadString(1);
  AllText := AllText + s;
  Go := True;
end;
```

Comment: I recommend to use a blocking library like Indy or Synapse for this task, as TServerSocket uses Windows event loop which makes it hard to use in a DLL application.

Comment: @mjn, i tried to use IdTCPServer, but result is the same. It also uses windows messages to call <code>OnExecute</code> event...

Comment: IdTCPServer does not use Windows messages, it is based on the Windows Winsock API. OnExecute is called in the main loop for a client connection, not in the Windows message loop.

Comment: @mjn, edited my post. I still cant make work even with TIdTCPServer.

Comment: Where is the form instance of TForm1 created (and the TCP server running), in the DLL or in the main application?

Comment: @mjn, in application. Dll has no forms at all.

Comment: MyWaitProc is in the DLL then? Have you tried it without the DLL first to see if the TCP server works as expected?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13313/discussion-between-astronavigator-and-mjn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TServerSocket` runs in non-blocking mode by default, which depends on processing window messages.  To remove that dependancy, you have to switch it to blocking mode instead.

`TIdTCPServer` runs in blocking mode exclusively, so no window messages. If you are having a problem with it, then you are misusing it.  For example, in your `TServerSocket` code, you do not set `Go = True` until after a response has been received, but in your `TServerSocket` code you are setting `Go = True` before reading a response instead.

As an alternative, have a look at Indy's `TIdSimpleServer` component.  `TIdSimpleServer` is synchronous and only accepts 1 connection at a time, whereas `TIdTCPServer` is asynchronous and accepts many connections at a time.  For example:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm) 
  ServerSocket: TIdSimpleServer; 

procedure MyWaitProc; stdcall; 
var
  s: String;
begin 
  ServerSocket.Listen;
  s := ServerSocket.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  ServerSocket.Disconnect;
  MessageBox(0, PChar('Received: '+s), '', MB_OK); 
end; 

exports 
  MyWaitProc;
```

Comment: Thanx, Remy. But in my case i need both asynchrony and ability to wait for response. I think synchronous component cannot resolve my problem, couse of some other functions in dll, which works asynchronously...

Comment: And also i need more than one connection.

Comment: Then you need a way of telling `MyWaitProc()` **which** connection it has to wait for. And then you need to fix that bug I pointed out earlier where `Go` is set to True too soon.

Comment: For now on i stopped on using TIdSimpleServer (in separate thread), so  i accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a loop that occasionally calls `Application.ProcessMessages` you can create a descendant of `TThread` and move the socket request  to the `TThread.Execute` method. Use TThread.OnTerminate to notify your form(or any other class) when the thread has completed its work.

There is [sample code](http://radstudiodemos.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/radstudiodemos/branches/RadStudio_XE/Delphi/RTL/Threads/) which gives more details about how to use `TThread`.

There are several other [3rd party](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3419945/71200) threading libraries that either provide more flexibility or are easier to use than `TThread` and I would highly recommend any of them over `TThread` if you are new to multi-threading.

Note: There are some serious [side-effects](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm) to using `Application.ProcessMessages`. You are seeing one of them in your code with the dll unlocking the application's mainform. It breaks the single-threaded UI model the VCL is build upon.  `ProcessMessages` has its place but using threads is more appropriate for the situation you're describing.

```
var Slowpoke: TMyLongRunningProcessThread;

procedure MyWaitProc(Completed:TNotifyEvent)
begin
  Slowpoke := TMyLongRunningProcessThread.Create(True);
  Slowpoke.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Slowpoke.OnTerminate := Completed;
  Slowpoke.Resume;
end;
```

`MyWaitProc` returns immediately after starting the thread so the GUI is free to respond to user actions. When the thread terminates it calls the event handler pointed to by `Completed`.

Obviously if you need to retrieve data from the thread you'll want to either have the thread write to an accessible memory location before it Frees itself or remove the `FreeOnTerminate` so the data can be retreived from the thread through a property.

Comment: I am not sure i understand you, Kenneth, which call in my dll i am to move to a thread? And how can i notify a form, in case my dll has no form at all?

Comment: Kenneth, i know how to use TThread (however thanx for your examples), but i still dont understand how it can resolve my problem...

Comment: Ken, thanx for answer. But i NEED my procedure not to end until it receives request from socket. It seems strange, but that is what i need... (i really need my GUI to be locked when waiting)

Comment: As soon as I stopped on using TIdSimpleThread in separate Thread, I vote up your answer for threading idea. Thanx :)